# freebsd shpgperproc what is responsible for?

Tags: performance, freebsd, sysctl

i've googled a lot about what is "page share factor per proc" responsible for and found nothing. It's just interesting for me, i have no current problem with it for now, just curious (wnat to know more). In sysctl it is:

```
vm.pmap.shpgperproc
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've figured out that this parameter levers (probably, i'm not 100% sure) on pv entries count... but how? freebsd kernel sources grep found nothing. or i've searched not so hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `shpgperproc` is a loader tunable, so it can only be set at boot time with an appropriate directive in `loader.conf`, and it's read-only after that.

The second thing to note is that it's defined in `<arch>/<arch>/pmap.c`, which handles the architecture-dependent portions of the vm subsystem. In particular, it's actually not present in the amd64 `pmap.c` - it was removed fairly recently, and I'll discuss this a bit below. However, it's present for the other architectures (i386, arm, ...), and it's used identically on each architecture; namely, it appears as follows:

```
    void
    pmap_init(void)
    {
            ...
            TUNABLE_INT_FETCH("vm.pmap.shpgperproc", &shpgperproc);
            pv_entry_max = shpgperproc * maxproc + cnt.v_page_count;
```

and it's not used anywhere else. `pmap_init()` is called only once: at boot time as part of the vm subsystem initialization. `maxproc`, is just the maximum number of processes that can exist (i.e. `kern.maxproc`), and `cnt.v_page_count` is just the number of physical pages of memory available (i.e. `vm.stats.v_page_count`).

A `pv_entry` is basically just a virtual mapping of a physical page (or more precisely a `struct vm_page`, so if two processes share a page and both have them mapped, there will be a separate `pv_entry` structure for each mapping. Thus given a page (`struct vm_page`) that needs to be dirtied or paged out or something requiring a hw page table update, the list of corresponding mapped virtual pages can be easily found by looking at the corresponding list of `pv_entry`s (as an example, take a look at `i386/i386/pmap.c:pmap_remove_all()`).

The use of `pv_entry`s makes certain VM operations more efficient, but the current implementation (for i386 at least) seems to allocate a static amount of space (see `pv_maxchunks`, which is set based on `pv_entry_max`) for `pv_chunk`s, which are used to manage `pv_entry`s. If the kernel can't allocate a `pv_entry` after deallocating inactive ones, it panics.

Thus we want to set `pv_entry_max` based on how many `pv_entry`s we want space for; clearly we'll want at least as many as there are pages of RAM (which is where `cnt.v_page_count` comes from). Then we'll want to allow for the fact that many pages will be multiply-virtually-mapped by different processes, since a `pv_entry` will need to be allocated for each such mapping. Thus `shpgperproc` - which has a default value of 200 on all arches - is just a way to scale this. On a system where many pages will be shared among processes (say on a heavily-loaded web server running apache), it's apparently possible to run out of `pv_entry`s, so one will want to bump it up.

Comment: one more question: can fragmented memory use increase consumption of `pv_entry`s?

Comment: Well, a `pv_entry` is allocated for every mapped page, so if memory is fragmented at a granularity smaller than the page size then presumably yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a FreeBSD machine close to me right now but it seems this parameter is defined and used in pmap.c, http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/ident?v=FREEBSD7&im=bigexcerpts&i=shpgperproc

Comment: so, i've found that "pv_entry_max = shpgperproc * maxproc + cnt.v_page_count;", but freebsd's sysctl has vm.pmap.pv_entry_max parameter. what's the difference?

Comment: maybe shpgperproc impact on initial pv_entry_max value that i can tune later?